# Gitlab pages is giving me a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gitlab

Hello my gitlab pages is giving me a blank page. Fixed json for the homepage and i made sure the yml file is correct. I added a H1 to my index file and that shows on the DOM perfectly! Please help.

[Here's my gitab](https://gitlab.com/DarionSuggs/githubcard)

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You're basically suggesting we download, run, and debug your code--what steps have you taken? What's in the JS console? Have you tested it locally?

Comment: Did you run npm build in your create-react-app? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: I've run npm start and it shows everything. I haven't run build cmd. I thought gitlab does that for you. @SydneyY

Comment: Nope, npm start runs a Dev server for you, but in order to show the website on a real server you have to run npm build before you upload it.